# How can I get consumer authorization in Postman - Magento2?

Tags: magento2.2.2, rest-api, postman

I am trying to get result for the existing magento api service ex.customer details (or) product details by sku, I am facing issue like below, give solution

```
"message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
"parameters": {
    "resources": "Magento_Customer::customer"
}
```

Comment: Magento is using resource `Magento_Customer::customer` for this and because of this we can't access it using Customer's token so for the same we need to override Specific API with OR Use Admin token for the same.

Comment: Hello @SUBBULAKSHMI G, please check the answer.

Comment: How can I get admin token? how to execute in Postman?

Comment: if any answer solves your concern then please mark as right for future readers, or post your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Endpoint**

```
POST http://<host>/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token
```

**Header**

```
Content-Type application/json
```

**Payload**

```
{
"username": "admin",
"password": "123123q"
}
```

**Response**

Magento returns the admin’s access token.

- This token must be specified in the authorization header of every
  call that requires admin permissions.

---

Magento is using resource `Magento_Customer::customer` for this and because of this we can't access it using **Customer's token** so for the same we need to **override** Specific API with OR you need to use **Admin's token**

`<resource ref="self" />`

And using this we can access all data of a specific customer using customer's Token in Magento API.

> OR you need to use Admin token instead of customer token

- and if you want to use **customer token** then you need to change
  `webapi.xml` resource

For an example : **Customer data**

```
   <!-- Customer Account -->
<route url="/V1/customers/:customerId" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface" method="getById"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

> I replaced resource `<resource ref="Magento_Customer::customer"/>` to
>   `<resource ref="self"/>`